# GitHub Lists in README.md

Tags: github

So I have a Bugs And Errors section on my Github Repo.
In that section I have a list with Bugs.
I was wondering is there a way to make "v" sign for completeed object in list be green or any other color.Because The "v" current color is too bright you can see it but you need to really concentrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use HTML entity `&#9989;` it will look like this: ✅

Other options here: http://graphemica.com/search?q=check

Hope it helps.

Comment: Like this: - [x&#9989;] Text

Comment: or this : &#9989;- [x] Text